# Arrow/ball tool to move objects on Freecad

Tags: vector

Good day all,

Using Freecad (on Ubuntu), I am searching for the tool to move graphically objects . The tool is made of three arrows and three balls of color green blue and red.

I just cannot find any info to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you seek is called the transform feature. According to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WMgJRa96VI) on the YouTube, it is a new feature from version 0.17 and was not available for version 0.16.

It is activated by double-clicking on the object you wish to manipulate. The video indicates that you must be in the Part workbench but I do not know if that is an exclusive requirement.

I found this video and other resources by using "move tool Freecad" in my preferred search engine. The results included transform along with move. Move in Freecad is a different process with other features, but the search results provided the clue to the term transform. Transform is a common term in many modeling programs for this type of manipulation.

[image: transform tool image]

Above image from [Freecad User Book](https://bassmatifreecad.github.io/FreecadUserBook/en/asm3/arch.htm) site.